# How to handle a record save event in salesforce lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning, lightning-experience

I have implemented the record edit according to instructions given in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordEdit.htm?search_text=channel. Everything is working correctly except the recordSaveSuccess event and its handler.
Below I have included my code.{!c.save} is not called. Am I doing something wrong?

/**Markup**/

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.openActivityList}" var="activity">
    <tr onmouseenter="{!c.showEditIcon}" onmouseleave="{!c.hideEditIcon}"> 
        <td>   
            <c:DFActivityCardCmp activity="{!activity}" uiThemeDisplayed="{!v.uiThemeDisplayed}"/> 
        </td>
        <td class="vertical-align-center iconDiv">
            <div class="slds-hide"> 
                <i aura:id="editIcon" data-id="{!activity.activityId}" class="fa fa-pencil" onclick="{!c.editActivity}"></i>
            </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

I have embedded the lightning component in Account page with a new tab.

/**Handler**/

```
<aura:handler name="onSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.save}"/>
```

/**Controller methods**/

```
editActivity : function(component, event, helper) {/**Opens edit popup**/
    var recordId = event.target.dataset.id; 
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();
},

save : function(component, event, helper) {/**handler method**/
    console.log("record saved");
}
```

Comment: Look this link to handle recordsaveSuccess https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm

Comment: I tried this <aura:handler name="onSaveSuccess" event="force:recordSaveSuccess" action="{!c.save}" /> . But its not working.

Comment: please,Post your full code

Comment: @vignesh Please check edits in the question. Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: what if the saveRecord throws an exception? how we can handle it on this component?

Answer (score 2):

`force:recordSaveSuccess` is used with the `force:recordEdit` component

```
<force:recordEdit aura:id="edit" recordId="{!v.recordId}" />
```