# Callback after force:editRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wish to use e.force:editRecord and NOT force:recordEdit, and still have my base page refreshed after successful save and closing of the modal, using an event like [force:recordSaveSuccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordSaveSuccess/documentation).

Is this even possible?

I am not having any issue with refreshing the page with e.force:refreshView. It is just that it is being called BEFORE the actual save has happened.
So what I need is a callback.

I have seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188076/callback-on-e-forceeditrecord-lightning-event) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159482/callback-event-on-a-gete-forceeditrecord-in-lightning/) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157329/how-to-handle-a-record-save-event-in-salesforce-lightning) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151685/how-to-find-out-when-forceeditrecord-dialog-is-closed-after-saving-changes) but nothing work for me.

Problem: The force:recordSaveSuccess and force:recordSave don’t fire after the record is edited successfully, at least now in Spring 19.

Comment: I used this workaround https://metillium.com/2017/09/use-showtoast-for-taking-action-after-lightning-record-edit/ and used force:showToast to solve my problem. I am not adding it as an answer as it is a workaround and not a proper solution.

Comment: It would be great to know if Salesforce is working on this. Because I see plenty of questions in StackExchange regarding this but none without any proper answer.